# Does Python intern the elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, object

```
num = [1, 2, 3]
```

As far as I know, the `num` list contains references to the `int` objects. Since the values are in the range `[-5, 256]`, I feel that they should be cached. Am I correct in my assessment?

Comment: Caching of small ints is an internal implementation detail.  If you ever find yourself in a situation where it matters whether or not this is happening, *you are doing something horribly wrong*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> 1 is lst[0]
True
```

Seems to be the case on my build (CPython 3.8).

The interning mechanism should not care about what references (variable names, list positions, ...) point to the object - they are unidirectional anyway.

Comment: *"The interning mechanism should not care about what references (variable names, list positions, ...) point to the object - they are unidirectional anyway."* - What do you mean by this?

Comment: @NSR a Python object does not know by which references it can be accessed (e.g. `lst[0]` or `my_int_var`). So whether an object is interned or not is unrelated to the fact that the object happens to be accessible by indexing into some list the object does not even know exists.

Answer (score 0):

Any list? No. Most objects are not cacheable.

This list? Yes, because they're integers in the range [-5, 256] like you said.

Keep in mind this is an implementation detail of CPython.